# how does the Semi Colon work while using out.write?

Tags: java, string, csv

While using out.write to write to a CSV file I realized that I need to use a Semi Colon as a part of the string that will be written out, examples:

```
out.write("Project Name;");

out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.getProjectName()) + ";");
```

I also realized that not using the Semi Colon will mess things up!

So could someone please descripe how this Semi Colon works and how does the compiler read it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "will mess things up"? What exactly is the problem if you omit the semicolon?

Comment: @Mureinik Sure! for example I have those strings will be written once as coulmns names in the CSV file:
 out.write("Project Name;");
                out.write("Type;");
                out.write("License;");
                out.write("Size;");
                out.write("JAVA Percentage;");
                out.write("Contributors;");
                out.write("Version;"); 
If I dont write or miss one of these semi colons, the next string will be written in the same cell as the previous one!

Comment: This has nothing to do with compilation, it's just the format for CSVs - you need a delimiter between cells (although a comma is usually used).

Comment: CSV is a plain text format. I recommend you open a CSV file on Notepad to see what's going on. Also you might want to make yourself familiar with the format you are trying to write, at the very least read the corresponding Wikipedia article. (Relatively to the format's incomplexity, there are far too many bad CSV implementations out there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing a semicolon it gets to know that one cell's data is completed and now it has to begin filling data in the next cell.
By using semicolon you can also fill data in multiple cells using only one out.write() statement viz., `out.write("somedata;someotherdata;");`. This is beauty of the language.

Comment: That sounds really intersting, I have to try this now ! :)

Comment: Yup try it and let me know the results.

Comment: Yup it Works :D , but is it the compiler that is resposible for that or is it the CSV file format, as the guy who commented my post mentioned?

Comment: Compiler doesn't have to do anything here as it understands only java code. and here it takes as a string and pass it in the outputstream. it doesn't bother if u have put semicolons or not. it is csv format which does it.